# Enter Cyprus on Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, cyprus

I am an Indian Passport holder, living in UK and have a valid Schengen Visa which allows multientry- Catergory C. I have a plan to visit Cyprus in April. Can Cyprus be my first port of entry on a Schengen Visa? I was supposed to travel to France in March but was unable to due to the on-going strikes. I am not sure if Cyprus can be by first port of entry on a Schengen Visa which is not used?

Comment: Cyprus is not *in* the Schengen area.  It therefore cannot be a port of entry into the Schengen area.  That doesn't mean that you can't go to Cyprus, however.

Comment: Yes, you can enter Cyprus on your visa.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Cypriot Embassy in Finland](https://cyprusembassy.fi/main/index.php?p=Consular_Section/8), you can use a multi-entry Schengen visa to enter Cyprus **if you have already used that visa to enter a Schengen country**:

> Third country nationals, holders of a valid Schengen visa (type:
>   double or multiple entry), who have already entered the Schengen area
>   in accordance with the terms upon which their Schengen visa was
>   issued, may travel to Cyprus without a Cypriot national visa

This suggests that Cyprus **cannot** be the first destination you visit with the visa. You could in theory stop off in a Schengen country on the way, although it's probably best if that's the country that issued the visa.

EDIT: [Timatic](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm#) (the database of visa requirements used by airlines) doesn't mention needing to have used the visa already:

> Passengers with a double or multiple entry C visa issued by Bulgaria,
>   Croatia, Romania or a Schengen Member State valid for the period of
>   intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.